# reactjs wrapper for Twilio Browser Call

Tags: java, node.js, reactjs, twilio

I am trying to build a reactjs wrapper for browser call feature using Twilio. I am getting the capability token by calling java rest API. Installed twilio using npm. In my react component i imported the twilio and trying to set up the Device using the token. But getting an error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setup' of undefined'. Can anyone suggest me how can I get rid of the error? Please suggest me a good approach to achieve the functionality. Thank you.

```
import twilio from 'twilio';
setup(){
        var token = //getting token here by calling a rest api;
        twilio.Device.setup(token);
  }
```

Comment: Before someone can help you, you will have to share the relevant piece of code.

Comment: Does that API even exist in their JS bindings? I couldn't find it in [the docs](http://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/) nor on [GitHub](https://github.com/twilio/twilio-node)

Comment: https://www.twilio.com/docs/quickstart/java/client/hello-monkey

Comment: Hi laks, were you able to debug the above issue? If not, could you provide more log details from the console output. Also seeing the full code for token generation could be helpful. Cheers!